# Suppress Drupal status messages by role?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Is it possible to suppress the status messages set by drupal_set_messages() for certain roles? One client does not want certain roles (anonymous) to see these messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Untested)

global $user;

```
  <?php if (!in_array('anonymous', array_values($user->roles)) && $show_messages && $messages): ?> 
      <?php print $messages; ?>          
  <?php endif; ?>
```